# Facebook FQL Javascript result set

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-fql

I am very new to Facebook integration and have hit a wall which I hope someone can help me with. I have read through many articles and tested various code samples to achieve what I need and I think the nearest I can get is FQL and JavaScript. I go into exactly what I am going to use it for but basically I need to retrieve data from a Facebook table and present the results in a html page.

I have this working when querying a single item when something is = to something, the single result is printed to screen in my html page but when I alter the query so that it returns more than one result the code seems to be failing without any errors.

Here is an example query I am trying to get working in the sample javascript code below but it returns a javascript error. I know the query is good because it can be tested here.

**Test page for FQL SQL queries** 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/

**example query**
SELECT name, pic_square, profile_url FROM user WHERE contains('sam roberts')

**Error when above query repalces query in working example below.**

SCRIPT1006: Expected ')' 
facebook_2.html, line 29 character 95

Here is my working example that retrieves just a single row of data, you can run this but it needs to be on a web server.If you have any advice please let me know, I really need it to work in JavaScript as this is the only language I have experience in.

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="msg"></div>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : '2xxxxxx',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
      </script>

      <script>
        function doSomething()
        {
            FB.init({appId: '2xxxxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
            var query = FB.Data.query('select name, uid from user where uid=742375122');
            query.wait(function(rows)
            {
             document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'name is ' + rows[0].name;
            });

        }


      </script>



      <input type="button" value="Click here" onClick="doSomething()">
    </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks for looking.

Comment: What do you have on **line 29 character 95** in **facebook_2.html**? This is a place where your problem is located. Did you pasted the code exactly as is without modification? The sample you provided works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

try using "SELECT name, pic_square, profile_url FROM user WHERE contains('sam roberts')"
seems like a string getting cut problem.

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="msg"></div>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
      <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : '283998891634567',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true
          });
        };
        (function(d){
           var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
           d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
         }(document));
      </script>

      <script>
        function doSomething()
        {
            FB.init({appId: '283998891634567', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
            var query = FB.Data.query("SELECT name, pic_square, profile_url FROM user WHERE contains('sam roberts')");
            query.wait(function(rows)
            {
             document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'name is ' + rows[0].name;
            });

        }


      </script>



      <input type="button" value="Click here" onClick="doSomething()">
    </body>
 </html>
```